# Code to do Monte Carlo using SPSS?

Tags: spss, monte-carlo

Is SPSS command code available for doing Monte Carlo research?

Thanks.

Comment: please be more specific.

Answer (score 2):

Statistics does not have a built-in Monte Carlo system, but all the ingredients are present.  There are many random number generators, and you can use an INPUT PROGRAM to generate random datasets.  There is a custom dialog box interface for generating random datasets.  The package is called makedata.zip.  It is in the Utilities Collection on the SPSS Community website (www.ibm.com/developerworks/spssdevcentral) and requires the Python Essentials also available from that site.

HTH,
Jon Peck